# ngResource - doesn't show data in browser

Tags: angularjs, factory, ngresource

i have problem with ngResource. 
here is my **.factory**

```
app.factory('sveKlupeServiceFactory', ['$resource',
 function($resource){
return $resource('myURL/to/json', {},{
// { method: 'getKlupe', q: '*' },
 query: { method: 'GET', params:{klupaId:'klupe'}, isArray:true}
 });
```

and here is my **controller**

```
app.controller('klupeController', ['$scope', 'sveKlupeServiceFactory', function ($scope,sveKlupeServiceFactory){
$scope.klupe = sveKlupeServiceFactory.query();
  }]);
```

and in **html** I have this

```
<tr ng-repeat="klupa in klupe">
           <td>{{klupa.serial_number}}</td>
             <td>{{klupa.location_id}}</td>
             <td>{{klupa.type}}</td>
             <td>{{klupa.last_report_dt}}</td></tr>
```

Problem:
in my browser I have table, but with empty row. There is no any error.

In my app I have

```
var app = angular.module('App', [
'ngRoute',
'ngResource']);
```

Can someone help me with any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: Hi, there is no any error

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your controller(or a console.log) and verify if $scope.klupe contains the data

Comment: in console log they give me d {$promise: d, $resolved: false}$promise: d$resolved: truesmart_benches: Array[7]__proto__: Object
controllers.js:26 d {$promise: d, $resolved: false}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want entire table data, then there is no need to pass id as parameters in factory.Make the following changes in controller while calling factory method.
Check the response using console.log()

```
sveKlupeServiceFactory.query(function(res){
console.log(res);
$scope.klupe = res;
});
```

Comment: thnx, i want all data, and then when i click on specific row to show mi data for that id.

Answer (score 0):

You should use promises to get the response.

```
$scope.klupe = sveKlupeServiceFactory.query();
$scope.klupe.$promise.then( function(result) { $scope.klupe = result });
```

Comment: thnx, now i have this, but still same, table is empty  $scope.klupe = sveKlupeServiceFactory.query(function(res){
       $scope.klupe.$promise.then( function(result) { $scope.klupe = result;}); 
       console.log($scope.klupe);
    });

Comment: No men, it is two line, like I wrote. check my code again. Why the query method has that parameter, it should not has parameters as you sample code show.

Comment: sry, i paste wrong, i type in my ctrl like you wrote. and there is same.  Which parameters i need? I found this parameters in topic here on forum. This is my json if this can help {"pametna_klupa":[{"id":1,"created_at":"2016-04-21T09:43:30+0200","modified_at":"2016-04-21T09:43:30+0200","serial_number":"121sdfgde43547zuxh","token":"a12nii1h21h124slgk34jk3l242422skgfjk000wet55","location_id":4343,"type":"urban","description":"lipa klupa","is_active":true,"time_zone":null,"last_report_dt":null,"last_ip":null}]}

Comment: Well the only change now should be `$scope.klupe = result.pametna_klupa[0]` to get the first element in the array on the resposne.

Comment: thnx, but i have many arrays, and i want to show all, and then, when i click on one to show mi all information of that klupa and to make CRUD.